# Equivalent query for SQL query with left join

Tags: linq, entity-framework-core

I have the following SQL query that has left join with tow parameters

```
select val1,val2 from  tbl1 
left join tbl2 on (tbl1.ID = tbl2.ForKey1 or tbl1.id= tbl2.ForKey2)
```

What is the equivalent Linq query to it that retrieve the same result ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use documented [Collection selector references outer in a non-where case](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/complex-query-operators#collection-selector-references-outer-in-a-non-where-case)

```cs
var query = 
   from tbl1 in ctx.tbl1 
   from tbl2 in ctx.tbl2
      .Where(tb2 => tbl1.ID == tbl2.ForKey1 || tbl1.id == tbl2.ForKey2)  
      .DefaultIfEmpty()
   select new 
   {
      tbl1,
      tbl2
   };
```